# Replace tip of newick file using reference list in bash

Tags: bash, genetics

I have a collection of newick-formatted files containing gene IDs:

```
((gene1:1,gene2:1)100:1,gene3:1)100;
((gene4:1,gene5:1)100:1,gene6:1)100;
```

I have a list of equivalence between gene ID and species name:

```
speciesA=(gene1,gene4)
speciesB=(gene2,gene5)
speciesC=(gene3,gene6)
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
((speciesA:1,speciesB:1)100:1,speciesC:1)100;
((speciesA:1,speciesB:1)100:1,speciesC:1)100;
```

Any idea of how I could proceed? Ideally in bash would be awesome :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

input.txt

```
((gene1:1,gene2:1)100:1,gene3:1)100;
((gene4:1,gene5:1)100:1,gene6:1)100;
```

equivs.txt

```
speciesA=(gene1,gene4)
speciesB=(gene2,gene5)
speciesC=(gene3,gene6)
```

convert.sh

```
#!/bin/bash


function replace() {
    output=$1
    for line in $(cat equivs.txt)  #this will fail if there is whitespace in your lines!
    do
        #gets the replacement string
        rep=$(echo $line | cut -d'=' -f1)

        #create a regex of all the possible matches we want to replace with $rep 
        targets=$(echo $line | cut -d'(' -f2- | cut -d')' -f1) 
        regex="($(echo $targets | sed -r 's/,/|/g'))"

        #do the replacements   
        output=$(echo $output | sed -r "s/${regex}/${rep}/g")
    done
    echo $output
}

#step through the input, file calling the above function on each line.
#assuming all lines are formatted like the example!
for line in $(cat input.txt)
do
    replace $line
done
```

output:

```
((speciesA:1,speciesB:1)100:1,speciesC:1)100;
((speciesA:1,speciesB:1)100:1,speciesC:1)100;
```

Comment: Any explanation for the code (even as code comments) would be nice

Comment: `for line in $(cat file)` is a bad idea - see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor. You should use a `while read` loop, or better yet, use the right tool for the job, which in this case is awk.

Comment: It's fine if there are no spaces, @TomFenech Besides, I assumed I was just doing someone's homework, not curing cancer.

Comment: It's up to you whether you take my advice or not, I'm just trying to help improve your answer.

Comment: My answer is terrible, but not because of my use of 'for'.

Comment: Thanks very much! Indeed, as of the whitespace, I don't have any so it's working perfectly!

Comment: @tlorin heh, you should really listen to Tom. My answer is pretty terrible if your problem scales at all. I just whipped out a working solution hastily. Even though his answer looks confusing, it's much much better.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an awk one-liner that does what you want:

```
$ awk -F'[()=,]+' 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=a[$3]=$1;next}{for(i in a)gsub(i,a[i])}1' species gene
((speciesA:1,speciesB:1)100:1,speciesC:1)100;
((speciesA:1,speciesB:1)100:1,speciesC:1)100;
```

Go through the file containing the mappings between the species and genes, saving them as key-value pairs in the array `a`. `NR==FNR` targets the first file passed to awk as the total line number `NR` is equal to the line number in the current file `FNR`. `next` skips any further instructions. Go through the second file and make the substitutions.

Comment: I can't accept both answers but thank you very much all the same! :)

Comment: @tlorin no problem. If, for whatever reason, you intend on using the answer you have accepted, I suggest that you at least run it through http://shellcheck.net, which will pick up the numerous bad practices it contains. However I would strongly recommend that you use the right tool for the job, which is awk. If there is anything I can do to explain my answer better, please let me know.